# How to create .ui file with hand code in an existing class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a Qt Creator C++ project which doesn't have `.ui` file to design the interface. The `.ui` was hand coded and now I need to assign this `.ui` file to the project.

Is there a way to assign this `.ui` file to the project without having conflicts?

Comment: If you are trying to code other UIs using a UI file no conflict will happen.  For the same Ui component, you'd better choose one of the aproaches.

Comment: the source code was not used Qt but used manuall or another approach to code user inteface. so now i need to do some changes with Qt but its not supporting those files as they were not implement using qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *handcode* `.ui` files in Qt, you need to right click in the file, on the **project explorer**, click on Open With and next on Plain Text Editor. Now you can copy and paste the `.ui` file that you already have!

It's **importantly** you specific the same name of all classes, objects, among other things, between the files and besides including the `.ui` file, you need to put the file on your constructor and declare her...

The method more **easier and faster**, is to create a new project with `.cpp, .h, .ui` files and paste all your code **without** erasing `ui` statements.

Comment: creating a new project is the best way i think as edit these files in qt make a mess

Comment: if the answer was useful to you, upvote her or mark as solution!